# Ternary Operator in For Loop causing infinite iterations

Tags: c, for-loop, infinite-loop, ternary-operator, operator-precedence

I was working on a function to transpose an `NxN` matrix which is stored in an array of `float`s. My first implementation seemed to cause the function to loop infinitely and I can't seem to figure out why. Here is the original code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numRows % 2 == 0 ? numRows / 2 : numRows / 2 + 1; i++)
{
    for(int j = i + 1; j < numColumns; j++)
    {
        //Swap [i,j]th element with [j,i]th element
    }
}
```

However the function never returns. Failing to see the error in my logic I rephrased the expression and now have the following working code:

```
int middleRow =  numRows % 2 == 0 ? numRows / 2 : numRows / 2 + 1;
for(int i = 0; i < middleRow; i++)
{
    for(int j = i + 1; j < numColumns; j++)
    {
        //Swap [i,j]th element with [j,i]th element
    }
}
```

Can anybody help explain why the first version does not work but the seemingly equivalent second version does?

Comment: Don't act like a jedi without being one, use parenthesis

Comment: keep the variable, your code looks way better with it and the optimiser will take care of it properly.

Comment: I often do not give the optimizer enough credit. Thank you for the advice, I will.

Comment: Yes no need for such complicated constructs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) table, `<` has higher priority over `?:`. You need to use `()` as required explicitly to enforce the required priority.

Change

```
for(int i = 0; i < numRows % 2 == 0 ? numRows / 2 : numRows / 2 + 1; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < ( numRows % 2 == 0 ? numRows / 2 : numRows / 2 + 1) ; i++)
```

**Note:** Please use the second approach. Much, Much better in readability, maintenance and understanding.

Comment: Thank you, I must study up on my operator precedence. This isn't the first time it has gotten me into trouble. Will accept this answer in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with the precedence of the operators.
If you want to keep the cluttered first version (which I don't recommend) use parenthesis:

```
i < (numRows % 2 == 0 ? numRows / 2 : numRows / 2 + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
i < ((numRows + 1) / 2)
```

If numRows is even, it will just be numRows/2. If odd, it will be numRows/2+1.

That will be faster and avoids branching due to the compare (unless you have a n excelent compiler which knows this pattern - unlikely.

You sometimes have to step back to see the whole picture.